# How do I put "tomato" in dialog when stressing the alternate pronouciation?

Tags: formatting

I want to have a character say "potato tomato" as a joke, stressing the tomahto pronunciation. How should I write this?

"Potato *tomahto*."  ?

Comment: Duplicate on ELU: [Correct, clear, concise way to use "potato-potato" in writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/181757/191178)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Look here!" he spit through his teeth, red-faced, "You can't say 'Toe-MAH-toe' and expect to be treated like a local! Have you even heard all these ladies yammering over at the produce aisle?" At this point, there was no hope of remaining discreet. I just stared blankly back at him, waiting for the show to end. "They all said it like they were born here. Like *you* were supposed to have been!"

"Toe-MAY-toe?"

"By God man! Not at all! Has your tongue been... Open up your mouth! Go ahead, I want to check if you have brought all your equipment. Is there a tongue in there?" He said this... tongue-in-cheek, I assumed. "Toe-MAH-toe! Go ahead, say it again!"

"Toe-MAH-toe?"

"Oh by the SAINTS you have done it man!!!" He wrangled me by my shoulders. "Soon we will be going into what that thing on the back of your car is again, and you'll blend right in."

"Oh, " I raised my finger as this reminded me, "We need to get some gas."

"PETROL! My... Oh, get in the car!"